# Jenkins - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I have configured the TFS repository in jenkins for maven build, while doing checkout i have been observing the below error for every new checkin it has been running 30 to 40 min finally giving the below error and continuing build, other then that if i broke/kill and re-trigger the build its going fine without an issue.

I have tried the below steps but is not helping out.

1.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" --> set the JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh.
```

2.

```
export JAVA_ARG="-Xmx1048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" --> set the JAVA_ARG in tomcat setenv.sh
```

3.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC" --> set CATALINA_OPTS in setenv.sh
```

**ERRRO logs:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rowset.DBRowSetHandler.handleRow
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rowset.RowSetParser.parseIndividualRow(RowSetParser.java:340)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rowset.RowSetParser.parseRows(RowSetParser.java:270)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rowset.RowSetParser.parse(RowSetParser.java:128)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata$3.performTask(Metadata.java:415)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.internal.db.ConnectionPool.executeWithPooledConnection(ConnectionPool.java:80)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata.updateMetadata(Metadata.java:353)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata.update(Metadata.java:540)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.metadata.Metadata.update(Metadata.java:490

Comment: Try to clear old builds that you don't need on your Jenkins server, too see whether it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the above issue got resolved after upgraded TFS plugin in jenkins(version-1.654). I have upgraded from TFS 1.12 to 3.20.

Comment: @Ashok Jayadeeban, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, please add your solution as an answer(not a comment), and mark it as the answer. So it would help other community members to find the answer easily. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The above issue got resolved after upgraded TFS plugin in jenkins(version-1.654). I have upgraded from TFS 1.12 to 3.20